# How to explain Category is Set-category, enriched in category: Set?

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory

In book: [https://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/teaching/sp18/7Sketches.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Edspivak/teaching/sp18/7Sketches.pdf) chapter: "4.4.4 Categories enriched in a symmetric monoidal category"
declared:

> categories should really be called Set-categories

My understand:
morphisms between $ a, b $ in Category are presented by set(morphism) elements in Set-category
$ id_x $ in Category is presented by morphism: $ I \to \mathscr{X}(x, x) $ in Set-category

But I don't know:
how Set-category present $ g \circ f \in \mathscr{C}(a, c) $ where $ f:a \to b, g: b \to c $ in Catgegory?
how Set-category present unitality and associativity in Category?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a category $C$ enriched in a monoidal category $V$ is a class $\mathrm{Ob}(C)$ together with an object $C(a,b)$ of $V$ for every $a,b,\in\mathrm{Ob}(C)$ and morphisms $C(b,c)\otimes C(a,b)\to C(a,c)$ for every $a,b,c\in\mathrm{Ob}(C)$ and $I\to C(a,a)$ for every $a$ such that the two ways of combining these morphisms to get from $C(c,d)\otimes \left(C(b,c)\otimes C(a,b)\right)$ to $C(a,d)$ are equal and such that the induced morphism $C(a,b)\cong I\otimes C(a,b)\to  C(b,b)\otimes C(a,b)\to C(a,b)$ and its right-handed analogue are the identity of $C(a,b)$.

If you set $V$ to be Set, then this is simply the word-for-word definition of a locally small category (many authors assume all categories to be locally small,) with the associativity and unitality constraints stated in terms of the composition functions rather than their values on individual morphisms.

More specifically: a locally small category is a class $\mathrm{Ob}(C)$ together with a set $C(a,b)$ for every $a,b\in \mathrm{Ob}(C)$ and functions $C(b,c)\times C(a,b)\to C(a,c)$ (mapping $(g,f)\mapsto g\circ f$) and $\{*\}\to C(a,a)$ (mapping $*$ to $\mathrm{id}_a$) such that the two ways of combining the composition functions to compose three morphisms are equal (the two ways being those that send $(f,g,h)\in C(c,d)\times C(b,c)\times C(a,b))$ to $f\circ(g\circ h)$ and $(f\circ g)\circ h$) and the induced function $C(a,b)\cong \{*\}\times C(a,b)\to C(b,b)\times C(a,b)\to C(b,b)$ (sending $f$ to $(*,f)$ to $(\mathrm{id}_b,f)$ to $\mathrm{id}_b\circ f$) and its right-handed analogue are the identity functions.

Comment: To be precise, what we get is a locally small category. But it seems that many authors assume categories to be locally small (and I did this also most of the time, but start to regret this decision ...).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, of course. I'm never quite sure which I want myself.

Comment: Please correct me if my understanding is wrong:  
$\exists$ $ C(a, a) \otimes C(a, b) \to C(a, b) $ and  $ C(a, b) \to C(a, a) \otimes C(a, b)  $ so $ C(a, a) \otimes C(a, b) \cong C(a, b)$.  

But what I don't get is that: $C(a, a)$ and $C(a, b)$ are sets which means $ (c_n \times c_m) \cong  c_m $ for ALL $c_n \in C(a, a)$, $c_m \in C(a, b)$. But as a Category say it D only $id_a \otimes D(a, b) \cong D(a, b) $ not $D(a, a) \otimes D(a, b) \cong D(a, b)$

Comment: @SharkXu I'm not following. There is a morphism $C(a,a)\otimes C(a,b)\to C(a,b)$, the composition, and another morphism $C(a,b)\to C(a,a)\otimes C(a,b)$, the left unitor. But these are not isomorphisms, and it's certainly not the case that $C(a,a)\otimes C(a,b)\cong C(a,b)$ in general.

Comment: I think my category knowledge base can not follow you. What I learned is from book: https://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/teaching/sp18/7Sketches.pdf 
Can you kindly show your category definition and expand the "word-for-word"?

Comment: @SharkXu I’ve added some more details, but I’d also suggest you consider simply ignoring this side remark until such a time as you might find yourself studying a more in-depth category theory text.

Comment: @KevinArlin thank you very much for your kindly explain. I see that definition your are referring is very different from the one I am referring: https://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/teaching/sp18/7Sketches.pdf  section: 3.2 (page 81). 
I think better to raise a new question for explanation base on same definition. 
Anyway, thanks a lot for your explain again and again.